# Django how to auto generate a unique number/string for a model attribute

Tags: python, django

So i been trying to generate 10 digit unique random number in django model without making it my primary key. My model is

```
Class Transaction(models.Model):
      Referrence_Number = models.Charfield(max_lenght = 10, blank=True, editable=False, unique=True)
```

I know that Django has special feature inside it to generate random string that i came to know after reading documentation.

```
from django.utils.crypto import get_random_string
get_random_string(10).lower()
```

But my problem is how can i incorporate this get_random_string function inside my django transaction model in my Transcation_number Instance. I m actually new to django and cant able to figure it that out.

Comment: Any reason not to just use `get_random_string` as a default value generator for the field as discussed in [this sections](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#default) of the django docs?

Comment: what i came to know that  get_random_string generates 12 as default value, i m choosing 10 digit so that i can index it and can search the object through reference number. Me noob in django,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set a default on your attribute to a function that generates whatever `Referrence_Number` you'd like. Just don't set a `Referrence_Number` on record creation

For example, your model attribute would look like this:

```
from utils import create_new_ref_number

Class Transaction(models.Model):
      Referrence_Number = models.Charfield(
           max_length = 10,
           blank=True,
           editable=False,
           unique=True,
           default=create_new_ref_number
      )
```

And in your `utils.py` file, you'd have something like this:

```
import random

def create_new_ref_number():
      return str(random.randint(1000000000, 9999999999))
```

While you could simply throw the `randint` function in the `default` parameter, you should abstract it away so you can perform extra niceties like verify no record exists with that same id, etc.

Comment: What happens if create_new_ref_number accidently returns a number which has generated before. Does the model calls default function again or throws an error?

Comment: it creates non unique numbers too! And results into error

Comment: `CharField` typo mistake

Comment: Also you must remove parentheses after create_new_ref_number, i.e.: `default=create_new_ref_number,`. Otherwise, it will be called upon class definition when importing the module, generating a constant value.

Comment: @MasoodKhaari yes

Answer (score 13):

I normally use uuid, the uuid string will set to the field when create object

```
the_field = models.CharField(max_length=36, default=uuid.uuid4)
```

Answer (score 4):

This will automatically create a unique Referrence_Number

```
import random

class Transaction(models.Model):
    Referrence_Number = models.Charfield(
            max_length = 10,
            blank=True,
            editable=False,
            unique=True,
            default=create_new_ref_number
        )

    def create_new_ref_number():
                not_unique = True
                while not_unique:
                    unique_ref = random.randint(1000000000, 9999999999)
                    if not Transaction.objects.filter(Referrence_Number=unique_ref):
                        not_unique = False
                return str(unique_ref)
```

Answer (score -1):

Perhaps you could override the save() method on the Model. Something like this:

```
def save(self,*args, **kwargs):
    self.Reference_Number = get_random_string(10).lower()
    super(Transaction, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```