# ImportError: cannot import name 'create_new_ref_number' from 'utils' in Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework, importerror

I tried to create a random unique string in a charfield using create_new_ref_number() but it is giving me above error. I have already installed utils==1.0.1 and my django version is 2.2, as utils package are only allowed in lower django version.

The full error is :

**ImportError: cannot import name 'create_new_ref_number' from 'utils' (C:\Users\User\Desktop\RupseOnline\rupseonline\myvenv\lib\site-packages\utils_*init*_.py)**

My model is:

```
from utils import create_new_ref_number

class OrderItem(models.Model):
    #user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True
    orderItem_ID = models.CharField(max_length=12,unique=True,default=create_new_ref_number())
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order,on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True,null=True,related_name='order_items')
    item = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True, null=True)
    order_variants = models.ForeignKey(Variants,on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True,null=True)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)    
    total_item_price = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True,null=True,)
```

The issue arises when I try to run makemigrations.

Comment: Is there any reason in particular that you can't use UUID for Id?

Comment: Can you show us the classes you have in utils.py? The error meant utils do not have the class create_new_ref_number

Comment: @Saroj https://stackoverflow.com/a/59148235 this already answered your question

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django how to auto generate a unique number/string for a model attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59147127/django-how-to-auto-generate-a-unique-number-string-for-a-model-attribute)

Comment: Is says I have to write a function inside utils.py file, but there is no utils.py, instead there is a dir named utils which has diierent other files. @VJMagar

Comment: UUID generates random alphanumeric with - which is not very good, i just need 12 lenght characters @VJMagar

Comment: Answered here https://www.reddit.com/r/django/comments/mhpx33/importerror_cannot_import_name_create_new_ref/gt0xdrz?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3

Comment: I have tried importing the function inside the model.py itself and it worked, but there is an issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66915193/1062-duplicate-entry-81clzeczrw-for-key-orders-orderitem-orders-orderitem @VJMagar