# (1062, "Duplicate entry '81CLZECZRW' for key 'orders_orderitem.orders_orderitem_orderItem_ID_7d6cd69b_uniq'") on Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, api, django-rest-framework, postman, unique

I am trying to generate a uniq OrderItem_ID during the order create api. But, it generates the above error as **django.db.utils.IntegrityError:**

The first api is always successful from the postman, but in the second call I tried changing different products for creating the order, but I am getting this unique id order.

I have to remove the order_items from db , to create a new order_item object otherwise I get this unique error.

I am sending data like this.

[image]

My model:

```
import random
import string
# Create your models here.

def id_generator(size=10, chars=string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits):
   return ''.join(random.choice(chars) for _ in range(size))

class Order(models.Model):
    ORDER_STATUS = (
        ('To_Ship', 'To Ship',),
        ('Shipped', 'Shipped',),
        ('Delivered', 'Delivered',),
        ('Cancelled', 'Cancelled',),
    )
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True)    
    order_status = models.CharField(max_length=50,choices=ORDER_STATUS,default='To_Ship')

    ordered_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    ordered = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    total_price = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True,null=True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.email

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Orders"
        ordering = ('-id',)

class OrderItem(models.Model):    
    orderItem_ID = models.CharField(max_length=12,unique=True, editable=False, default=id_generator())
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order,on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True,null=True,related_name='order_items')
    item = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True, null=True)
    order_variants = models.ForeignKey(Variants,on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True,null=True)
    quantity = models.IntegerField(default=1)    
    total_item_price = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=True,null=True,)
```

My serializers:

```
class OrderSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    billing_details = BillingDetailsSerializer()
    order_items = OrderItemSerializer(many=True)
    user = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(read_only=True, default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault())
    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ['id','user','ordered_date','order_status', 'ordered', 'order_items', 'total_price','billing_details']
        # depth = 1   

    def create(self, validated_data):
        user = self.context['request'].user
        if not user.is_seller:
            order_items = validated_data.pop('order_items')
            billing_details = validated_data.pop('billing_details')
            order = Order.objects.create(user=user,**validated_data)
            BillingDetails.objects.create(user=user,order=order,**billing_details)
            for order_items in order_items:
                OrderItem.objects.create(order=order,**order_items)
           
            return order
        else:
            raise serializers.ValidationError("This is not a customer account.Please login as customer.")
```

In python shell, i tired this and it works fine

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is with

```
orderItem_ID = models.CharField(max_length=12,unique=True, editable=False, default=id_generator())
```

Here in the default, you're have assigned function call. Thus, it will only be evaluated once at the time of creation, .i.e., at first time you run makemigrations.

We need to have function references in the default values, this way it will be called each time a new instance is created.

Try replacing the line with

```
orderItem_ID = models.CharField(max_length=12,unique=True, editable=False, default=id_generator)
```

Note `default=id_generator` and not `default=id_generator()`.

Hope this answers your question.
PS: you would be required to rerun the makemigrations and migrations commands to set this change into effect.

Comment: Wow, it worked. Yes I  think its unique when I had run makemigrations. Thats why I was confused as I had to run makemigrations twice, one for addfield and another field alterfield when I created the field. Thanks @VJ Magar

Answer (score 0):

The validation error comes from here:

```
orderItem_ID = models.CharField(max_length=12,unique=True, editable=False, default=id_generator())
```

Add orderItem_ID in OrderItemSerializer and try sending orderItem_ID in "order_items" with a unique value on each post.

As for this: default=id_generator()

Check what this function is generating on each hit, probably its saving the same value each time which is causing the error.

Comment: I have added the orderItem_ID in the OrderItemSerializer, but I am getting the error. I tried removing as well, but same error. In postman, it is showing same Id and says unique error. I am stuck @Neeraj

Comment: did you check what values are being sent in payload or at the time of generation for orderItem_ID?

Comment: And what exactly does this function do? id_generator()

Comment: I am just calling it from a local server in postman, as it has not been live yet. id_generator is just a function, we can use any name for it @Neeraj

Comment: can you share the function? or check if its generating unique values everytime? Because your error pops up on second post not first, which means in second post the orderitem_id is sent same

Comment: In python shell, I tried calling id_generator() and it sends different UNIQUE char.. What function do you want me to share??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230662/discussion-between-saroj-paudel-and-neeraj).

Comment: Do this: Remove default= line in models, makemigrate and migrate. Add orderItem_ID in Item serailizer and each time you post manually send a unique item_id

Comment: Yes @Neeraj, its going to generate the same value for each instance of the orderitem. I have shared my answer explaining the reason.

Comment: Ah fair point @VJ Magar, didnt notice that. Saroj next time you should also check what the func calls are sending. Try using debugger mode and you'll understand the flow much better

Comment: Can you please provide me a good link for understanding debugger mode @Neeraj